# How to fix SSL rejection in offlineimap

Tags: ssl, imap, offlineimap

I installed `server.crt` created following the instructions in [Ubuntu certificates](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html.en). Here is the output when I attempt to run `offlineimap`. What do I need to do in order to get the SSL working?

```
OfflineIMAP 7.1.5
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
imaplib2 v2.57 (system), Python v2.7.15rc1, OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
Account sync Gmail:
 *** Processing account Gmail
 Establishing connection to imap.gmail.com:993 (Remote)
 ERROR: Unknown SSL protocol connecting to host 'imap.gmail.com' for repository 'Remote'. OpenSSL responded:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that the instructions I followed are for setting up a server to verify itself to clients, while offlineimap is a client and it actually needs to verify that Gmail is what it pretends to be and not some impersonator. so the setup needs to be

```
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

which is already available on Linux boxes and there is no need to do anything about setting up SSL.